# AsyncTask crash when scroll event

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a problem AsyncTask in android listview is not really a problem when running normally, so the condition when the user scrolls page down to next page when asyntask running, the direct application of force closed.

I've tried all the conditions as :

```
if (AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING == null) {
    / / My code do in backgroud here
}

if (backgroundtask.getStatus! = STATUS.RUNNING) {
    / / My code do in backgroud here
}
```

Always failed...

```
public abstract View getAmazingView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent);


public final View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View res = getAmazingView(position, convertView, parent);

        if (position == getCount() - 1 && automaticNextPageLoading) {
            onNextPageRequested(page + 1);
        }

        final int section = getSectionForPosition(position);
        boolean displaySectionHeaders = (getPositionForSection(section) ==  position);

        bindSectionHeader(res, position, displaySectionHeaders);

        return res;
    }


protected void onNextPageRequested(int page) {

            backgroundTask = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, List<Bola>>() {
                protected List<Bola> doInBackground(
                        Integer... params) {
                    int page = params[0];
                    return Adapter.getRows(page);
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(
                        List<Bola> result) {
                    if (isCancelled()){
                        backgroundTask.cancel(true);                        
                    }

                    list.addAll(result);
                    nextPage();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                    if (result.size() > 0) {
                        // still have more pages
                        notifyMayHaveMorePages();
                    } else {
                        notifyNoMorePages();
                    }
                };
            }.execute(page);
        }
```

How that can be run with the AsyncTask running condition, and user use scrolls down event?

**======= UPDATE MY LOG =======**

```
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131034281, class com.dhika.bola.application.ui.ListUtils) with Adapter(class android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter)]
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1548)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3490)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at com.dhika.bola.application.ui.ListUtils.onTouchEvent(ListUtils.java:445)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7262)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2235)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1932)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2241)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1946)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2241)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1946)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2241)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1946)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2241)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1946)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2241)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1946)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1968)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1420)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2428)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1916)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7442)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3610)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3538)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4790)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4750)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4902)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4870)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4924)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:546)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: add the logcat loggs please

Comment: What does nextPage()? If it has an operation which must run on the updated list view, better put that after notofiyDataSetChanged. And logcat output please.

Comment: @jmeier I have attached error log on the post above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly (from what you have tried) you want to avoid calling AsyncTask when it runs already. This should do the job:

```
// class variable
// boolean isRunning = false;

protected void onNextPageRequested(int page) {


    if (!isRunning) {

        isRunning = true;

        backgroundTask = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, List<Bola>>() {

            protected List<Bola> doInBackground(
                    Integer... params) {
                int page = params[0];
                return Adapter.getRows(page);
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(
                    List<Bola> result) {
                if (isCancelled()){
                    backgroundTask.cancel(true);                        
                }

                list.addAll(result);
                nextPage();
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                if (result.size() > 0) {
                    // still have more pages
                    notifyMayHaveMorePages();
                } else {
                    notifyNoMorePages();
                }


            };
        }.execute(page);
            isRunning = false;
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your LogCat error you modify your ListView data on another thread then the main thread.. as it says:

```
11-02 23:22:42.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25830): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131034281, class com.dhika.bola.application.ui.ListUtils) with Adapter(class android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter)]
```

**Starting a single `AsyncTask` multiple times is also not allowd.**

But there are some more things that are unclear to me:

1. Why are you doing the getRows() in the async task?
2. what does this `Adapter.getRows(page)` do (as this should be static method)? does is change something?
3. What are you generally trying to achieve? Do you want just to have one single AsyncTask at once?

Just one more note: I dont see you changing the adapter content in the AsyncTask but there (as the exception says it) should be something...

If you do it somewhere else do it either in the `onPostExecution` or with the `runOnUiThread` method.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

public void run() 
{
    //Update UI here                        
}
});
```